# Why this background is not working when I am writing my code further?

Tags: html, css

I'm writing the website code using HTML and CSS for now and I don't know why the same purple background color that I set at the beginning of my code for the whole body is getting break and it displays white background further. Here is the code for HTML and CSS.

### HTML Code

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta name="viewport" content="maximum-scale=1.0, initial-scale=1.0, user- 
    scalable=no, height=device-height, width=device-width">
        <meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no">
        <title>MAXMA</title>
        <meta name="description" content="Оплата только за клиентов, которых мы вам 
    вернули">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/style.css">
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2? 
     family=Montserrat:wght@100&family=Nuosu+SIL&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    </head>
    <body>
    <section>
        <div class="mainpage">
            <div class="header">
                <img class="logo" src="assets/images/logo-white.svg" alt="maxmaicon">
                <nav>
                    <ul class="header-menu">
                        <li><a href="#">Возможности</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Кейсы</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Цены</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </nav>
                <a class="header-contacts" style="font-size: 1.2em; margin-top: 6px; 
 line-height: 1.5;">
                    +7 (499) 938 49 80
                    <br>
                    hello@maxma.com
                </a>
                <p id="demo"><b>Посмотреть демо</b></p>
            </div>
            
            <div class="site-header"></div>
            
            <div class="body">
                <div class="body-text">
                    <h1>Платформа лояльности<br> 
                 <span style="color: rgb(98, 240, 98)">для ритейл сетей</span>
                    </h1>
                    
                  <input type="text" name="phone" id="phone" placeholder="Phone Number" 
 style="margin-left: 120px; margin-top: 120px; padding: 10px; width: 250px; height: 
 20px;">
                        <button id="watchbut">Посмотреть демо</button>
                        <p style="font-size: 0.8em; margin-left: 135px; margin-top: 5px; 
  color: whitesmoke;">Будет отправлен код по смс</p>
                    
                </div>
                <div class="body-video">
                    <div class="laptop1">
                        <img src="assets/images/laptop.png" alt="laptop1_image">
                        <video src="https://maxma.com/assets/video/lead-1080.mp4" 
 playinline autoplay muted loop></video>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            
            
            
            <div class="b-lead__nav mod-only-lg">
        
                <nav class="b-nav-lead" itemscope 
    itemtype="http://www.schema.org/SiteNavigationElement">
                      <a id="buts" itemprop="url" href="#" class="js-link-anchor btn- 
   primary" style="width: 180px;">Программа лояльности</a>
                      <a id="buts" itemprop="url" href="#" class="js-link-anchor btn- 
   primary">Сегментация базы</a>
                      <a id="buts" itemprop="url" href="#" class="js-link-anchor btn- 
   primary">Рассылки</a>
                      <a id="buts" itemprop="url" href="#" class="js-link-anchor btn- 
   primary">Приведи друга</a>
                      <a id="buts" itemprop="url" href="#" class="js-link-anchor btn- 
   primary">Другое</a>
                  </nav>
            </div>
            
            <div class="lead_clients" >
                <div class="clients_title">Наши клиенты<a class="stars" 
    href="https://startpack.ru/application/cloudloyalty/reviews"></a></div>
                <div class="clients_list">
                    
                </div>
            </div>
    
        </div>
    </section>
        
    
    </body>
    </html>

CSS Code
=======

    *{
        margin: 0;
    }
    .mainpage{
    
        height: 100vh;
    }
    li, a{
        text-decoration: none;
        color: white;
    }
    .header{
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: row;
        justify-content: space-between;
        align-items: center;
        margin-bottom: 1px;
    }
    .logo{
        cursor: pointer;
        margin: 2em;
    }
    .header-menu{
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: row;
        font-size: 1.5vw;
        gap: 15px;
        justify-content: center;
        list-style: none;
    }
    .header-menu li a{
        transition: all 0.3s ease 0s;
    }
    .header-menu li a:hover {
        color: #0088a9;
    }
    .body{
        display: flex;
        font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
        padding-top: 6em;
        margin-top: 30px;
    }
    .body-text{
        width: 50%;
    }
    .body-video{
        width: 50%;
    }
    .laptop1{
        width: 100%;
        max-width: 1200px;
        position: relative;
    }
    .laptop1 img{
        width: 80%;
    }
    .laptop1 video{
        position: absolute;
        width: 75%;
        height: 84%;
        top: 6%;
        left: 2.6%;
    }
    .body-text input [type=text]{
        float: left;
        width: 100px;
        padding: 6px;
        margin-top: 16px;
        margin-right: 8;
        border: 2px;
        font-size: 22px;
    }
    .site-header {
        border-bottom: 1px solid rgb(167, 160, 160);
    }
    #demo{
        border-radius: 20px;
        border: 1px solid white;
        padding: 20px; 
        width: 150px;
        height: 20px; 
        text-align: center;
        color: white;
        font-size: 1em;
        margin-right: 90px;
    }
    h1{
        font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
        font-weight: bold;
        font-size: 2.8em;
        margin-left: 120px;
        color: white;
        
        line-height: 1.5;
    }
    #watchbut{
        font-size: 1.3em;
        padding: 8px;
    }
    .b-nav-lead{
        display:-webkit-box;
        display:-ms-flexbox;
        display:flex}
    .b-nav-lead a:not(:last-child){
        margin-right: 18px;
    }
    .b-nav-lead .btn-primary{
        font-size:20px;
        border-radius: 20px;
        margin-left: 20px;
        padding-top: 200px;
    }
    .b-nav-lead .btn-primary:hover{
        background:#fff;
        border-color:#ffff;
        color:#6152d2;
        -webkit-box-shadow:0 6px 14px rgba(0,0,0,.16);
        box-shadow:0 6px 14px rgba(0,0,0,.16);
        -webkit-transition:-webkit-box-shadow .35s ease-out;
        transition:-webkit-box-shadow .35s ease-out;
        -o-transition:box-shadow .35s ease-out;
        transition:box-shadow .35s ease-out;
        transition:box-shadow .35s ease-out,-webkit-box-shadow .35s ease-out;
    }
    #buts{
        border-radius: 20px;
        border: 0.5px solid whitesmoke;
        padding: 20px; 
        width: 150px;
        height: 15px; 
        text-align: center;
        color: white;
        position: relative;
        font-size: 1em;
        margin-left: 30px;
        margin-top: 30px;
        padding-top: 18x;
        left: 80px;
        font-weight: bold;
    }
    #buts:hover{
        color: #4a42ba;
        background: #fff;
    }
    section{
        background-color: #4a42ba;
    }
    .lead_clients{
        margin: 80px;
    }
    .clients_title{
        text-align: center;
        font-size: 1.6em;
        font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
        color: #fff;
    }
```

if you run the code you can see that at the bottom of the page there are oval shapes that contain some text and this place is the last where the purple color background is applied. I don't know which part is making it to turn to white background after that cause I even gave the whole background for the section and it still displays the same thing.
P.S. Important thing is that I can't set the same background color for the whole body cause I need sections which would have different backgrounds but till this part I need it to be the same.

Answer (score 0):

you need to increase the `height` in `.mainpage` css class to `height:100%;`

Comment: Thank you very much! Would it work than if I would turn to another section and would decide to set another background-color for that section?

Comment: `.mainpage` css class is applied to the `<div>` tag which contains all of your other tags, so as long as your other section is inside the div which contains `mainpage` css it will inherit that background from its parent `div` tag or unless you assign your section css class which overwrites this `background: othercolor;` property.